# Downloading images from the server and saving in certain folder of project of app (app\src\main)

Tags: android

After downloading application (or after first openning of application) I want app to download images from the server and save them in certain folder of project. (app\src\main) In my case, in folder app\src\main\assets
How to do that?

Comment: Which part or do you just want all of it?

Comment: @Barns52 all images in one folder

Comment: So you already have the part that downloads the images operating properly? If so post your code shows how the images are downloaded.

Comment: @Barns52 Probably I have understood your question wrong. I bad know Engish so sorry... I don't have the part of dowloaded images. All images are stored in some site and I want to download from this site these images to my folder (app\src\main\assets)

Comment: At least I need to download these images in internal or external memory, i.e separately from app. (In this case, I guess I will can get around copyright infringement of images. Because in fact app does not contain copyrighted content)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have not given any information about where you are getting the image I will provide you with an example of a simple Http download.

**You will not be able to save any files to the applications `asset` folder! It is a read only repository.**

```
public byte[] HttpFileDownload(){
    byte[] result = null;
    try{
        String s = "http://www.yourDomain/" + getDataFileName(FILE_DATA_TYPE);
        URL url = new URL(s);

           URLConnection uc = url.openConnection(Proxy.NO_PROXY);
           InputStream content = (InputStream)uc.getInputStream();

           ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

           int nRead;
           byte[] data = new byte[1024];

           while ((nRead = content.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
               baos.write(data, 0, nRead);
           }

           baos.flush();

           result = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

FILE_DATA_TYPE will contain a string with the file name you wish to download (eg. lakesmith.jpg).

```
private boolean saveToFile(String fileName, byte[] ba){
    FileOutputStream outputStream;

    try {
        outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        outputStream.write(ba);
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: This answer is not intended to be a copy paste solution, but simply a push in a direction which works for me

Comment: Okey, thank you for your answer, I will try to figure out something.

Comment: Why method "saveToFile" is boolean?

Comment: And where does file save?

Comment: Sorry about the boolean, I edited down some code I used in an app. I returned a boolean to indicate if I was successful. I forgot to add that here.

Comment: To understand more about how files are stored on Android devices take a look at the docs. :: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files.html